# why is it necessary to set "network_mode: host" when containers of multi machine share same network on ubuntu on virtualbox

Tags: docker, networking, virtualbox, ros

HOST OS: Windows 10 / VirtualBOX

Guest OSA:

```
os: Ubuntu20.04 LTS
network adapter : internal network/nat
ip : enp0s8 static ip 172.168.0.1/255.255.255.0
```

Guest OSB:

```
os: Ubuntu20.04 LTS
network adapter : internal network/nat
ip : enp0s8 static ip 172.168.0.2/255.255.255.0
```

Docker version 20.10

ROS A: Container of Docker on Guest OSA on VirtualBOX

```
version ros2 dashing
```

ROS B: Container of Docker on Guest OSB on VirtualBOX

```
version ros2 dashing
```

it can communicate by UDP and TCP between GuestOSA and GuestOSB.(UDP: nc / TCP: ping)

Dockerfile

```
FROM ros:dashing
SHELL [“/bin/bash”, “-c”]
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-install -y net-tools iputils-ping ros-dashing-demo-nodes-cpp
```

GuestOSA

```
docker run -itd -p 42000:42000/udp imagesid /bin/bash
docker exec -it containername /bin/bash
```

ROS A

```
source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
```

GuestOSB

```
docker run -itd -p 42000:42000/udp imagesid /bin/bash
docker exec -it containername /bin/bash
```

ROS B

```
source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
```

this doesnt work!!
rosB cant catch any topic…

docker run -itd --net=host imagesid /bin/bash
it can work..

what difference..

Comment: `network_mode: host` generally disables Docker networking, and it's almost never necessary.  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating a setup where it doesn't work?  (In your multi-VM setup, you'll need to make sure each container has correct `ports:` published, and then connect to the other VMs' IP addresses and the published ports.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not required for the network to be set to `host` for the containers to communicate. The containers can publish a port trough which other containers can communicate with it. Which port to be exposed and published depends on the `ROS topic` configuration, since `ROS` supports both `TCP/IP` and `UDP/IP`. This requires for the `ROS topic` to use single port.

Comment: -windows / virtualboxA / ubuntuA / docker /  ros2A -windows / virtualboxB / ubuntuB / docker /  ros2B . if ros2A throw UDP broadcasting, ros2B could get?? ros2A can't get it when i tried. i need to use overlay.

Comment: ros2B # nc -lu 10000 / ros2A # nc  -u ros2BofIP 10000 / ros2A# test / it doesnt work..

Comment: Using overlay network will help you to have networking layer across the VMs, but it's not required. First check if you have issues with 1) ports not being published on the container, 2) firewall settings dropping packages. Use `docker run -p 100000:10000/udp` when starting the docker container and temporary stop firewalls.

Comment: thanks.. I editted my question. could you confirm it ? I have done that you say. but it doesnt work.

Comment: @たくまいわき From the update I see you are exposing only one UDP port. I expected to see more ports exposed (this once again depends on your configuration) or even range of ports. Best next step is to put one of the containers on host mode and use `tcpdump` on both hosts to check what type of traffic is flowing and on which ports. Also check this documents https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros2-behind-a-firewall/1178/2 describing the setup behind firewall. Firewall case is related since there also you need to know on which ports the trafic is flowing

Comment: @ jordanvrtanoski Thank you for your quick reply Honorifics

container A of UbuntuA(-p 4200:4200) :
#nc -lu -p 4200 
//not catch
UbuntuB: 
#nc -u 172.168.0.1 4200
#message
UbuntA: 
#tcpdump -i enps08 -A
message
//catch

container A of UbuntuA(-p 4200:4200) :
#nc -u 172.168.0.2 4200 
message
UbuntuB: 
#nc -lu 4200
#message
//catch

Comment: container A of UbuntuA(-p 4200:4200 4201:4201 4202:4202 4203:4203 4204:4204) it doesnt catch .

Comment: container A of UbuntuA (4000:7400 4001:250 4002:2 4003:4003 4004:10 4005:1 4006:11) it doesnt catch,